# HTTP GET request with AngularJS 2 and ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, http-get

How can I do HTTP GET request in AngularJS 2 with JavaScript (ES6)? The documentation only shows with TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that:

```
import {Http, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class SomeHttpService {
  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getSomething() {
    URLSearchParams params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('id', '1');
    return this.http.get('http://...', { search: params }).map(res => res.map());

    /*
      or if you need to subscribe in the service

      this.http.get('http://...').map(res => res.map())
               .subscribe(
                 (data) => {
                   // do something with data
                 }
               );
    */
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import the Angular2 Http module file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script> <---
```

and to set the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` providers when bootstrapping your application:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
(...)

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

In fact, the only thing that is specific to ES6 is the way to configure dependency injection with the static getter...

Comment: How i pass the parametres, for example 'id=1'

Comment: Using the `URLSearchParams` but it's not something specific to ES6... I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for our help, I will tr and post the result

Comment: What is HTTP_PROVIDERS?

Comment: `HTTP_PROVIDERS` contains the list of providers to use HTTP. It contains the `Http` one but also others that the `Http` class relies on. You need to define them to be able to inject an `Http` instance in your services or components.

Comment: i have this errors:
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level
 

import {Http} from '/angular2/http';

app.component.js (linha 1)
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level
 

import {Http, URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http';

Comment: You should define all imports at the beginning of your `app.component.ts` file. See this issue: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2259

Comment: i not using ts i'm using es6